# Launch Condition : Windows OS service pack version with OS bit

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, setup-deployment

For a windows application I am creating a Deployment project in `VS2010`. I want to add `Launch Condition` such as :

Setup  should start on :

- Windows XP having Service Pack 3 **For 32 bit**

  > OR
- Windows XP having Service Pack 2 **For 64 bit**

Currently I tried with Condition `(VersionNT = "501") AND (ServicePackLevel = "3")` but this condition only checks for Windows XP and Service Pack version 3 which works on 32bit Windows XP, but when I run on 64bit Windows XP It gives message that I have given.

So how can I check Windows version and Bit along with service pack version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved this by writing by this Launch Condition :

```
((VersionNT = "501") AND (Not VersionNT64) AND (ServicePackLevel = "3")) OR ((VersionNT = "501") AND (VersionNT64) AND (ServicePackLevel = "2"))
```

`VersionNT` and `ServicePackLevel` will check for Windows OS name and Service Pack version. read more @ https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370556%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

`VersionNT64` means 64bit of OS and `Not VersionNT64` OS is 32bit. read more @ http://blogs.flexerasoftware.com/installtalk/2010/11/using-msi-launch-conditions-to-prevent-installation-on-unsupported-windows-platforms.html